# clojure java.lang.NullPointerException while spliting string

Tags: clojure

I am new to clojure. I am trying to write a program which reads data from a file (comma seperated file) after reading the data I am trying to split each line while delimiter "," but I am facing the below error:

> CompilerException java.lang.NullPointerException,
>   compiling:(com\clojure\apps\StudentRanks.clj:26:5)

Here is my code:

```
(ns com.clojure.apps.StudentRanks)
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

 (defn student []
  (def dataset (atom []))
  (def myList (atom ()))
  (def studObj (atom ()))
   (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "e:\\example.txt")]
    (swap! dataset into (reduce conj [] (line-seq rdr)))
   )
  (println @dataset)
  (def studentCount (count @dataset))
  (def ind (atom 0))
  (loop [n studentCount]
  (when (>= n 0)
   (swap! myList conj (get @dataset n))
   (println (get @dataset n))
   (recur (dec n))))
  (println myList)
  (def scount (count @dataset))
  (loop [m scount]
 (when (>= m 0)
   (def data(get @dataset m))
   (println (str/split data #","))
   (recur (dec m))))
  )
(student)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `def` within functions, use `let`.

Comment: My suggestion is to slow down a bit. Being new to clojure you probably want to consider atoms, swap! and even loops as more advanced topics. You don't need any of those things to read lines from a file and split them. In fact you rarely need them, even in quite complex programs :-)

Comment: my requirement is read file content line by line and push each line into a list. for ex: my file content is "1,bharath,85,86,89,85" and requirement is: [(1 bharath 85 86 89 85)].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the first problem is that you are not writing correct Clojure.
To start, `def` should never be nested -- it's not going to behave like you hope. Use `let` to introduce local variables (usually just called locals because it's weird to call variables things that don't vary).
Second, block-like constructs (such as `do`, `let` or `with-open` evaluates to the value of their last expression.

So this snippet

```clj
(def dataset (atom []))
(with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "e:\\example.txt")]
  (swap! dataset into (reduce conj [] (line-seq rdr))))
```

should be written

```clj
(let [dataset
      (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "e:\\example.txt")]
        (into [] (line-seq rdr)))]
  ; code using dataset goes here
)
```

Then you try to convert dataset (a vector) to a list (`myList`) by traversing it backwards and consing on the list under construction. It's not needed. You can get a sequence (list-like) out of a vector by just calling `seq` on it. (Or `rseq` if you want the list to be reversed.)

Last, you iterate once again to split and print each item held in `dataset`. Explicit iteration with indices is pretty unusual in Clojure, prefer `reduce`, `doseq`, `into` etc.

Here are two ways to write `student`:

```clj
(defn student [] ; just for print
  (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "e:\\example.txt")]
    (doseq [data (line-seq rdr)]
      (println (str/split data #",")))))

(defn student [] ; to return a value
  (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "e:\\example.txt")]
    (into []
      (for [data (line-seq rdr)]
        (str/split data #",")))))
```

I hope this will help you to better get Clojure.

Comment: thanks a lot **cgrand**. now i understood it better.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a csv library:

```
(require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv])
(csv/read-csv (slurp "example.txt"))
```

Unless this is some file io exercise.